# How to query a value in redis in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

Assuming I have a structure such as:

```
house{rooms: 2, bathrooms: 1, square-feet: 1000},
house{rooms: 3, bathrooms: 1.5, square-feet: 1200},
house{rooms: 5, bathrooms: 3, square-feet: 1400},
```

Assuming I want to retrieve all houses where rooms  = 3, how would I do that? Currently the key for each object is the zipcode which I need to use to look up and sort. I know in mongoose you can do something like:

`var house = House.find({rooms: '3'});` 
but I can't find the equivalent command using redis.

Comment: You don't, unless you create another structure in redis keyed on # of rooms. There isn't any indexing in redis except what you build.

Comment: Thanks @hobbs.  Is there any inmemory cache object that would let me do the above? I guess if I want to do search by # of rooms, then I'd have to create a separate object that is basically a clone of the data of the current collection?

Answer (score 1):

Try the ZADD Command to sort the houses by #rooms
ZADD is a ordered set that allows indexing by numbers.

ZADD "sorted set name" "sorting value" "value" "key"

so in your example :

ZADD housesByRooms 2 house1 
ZADD housesByRooms 3 house2 
(and so on you can also add multiple values at once)

http://redis.io/commands/ZADD

later you can get them by ZRANGE

ZRANGE "sorted set name" "from" "to"
for example 
ZRANGE housesByRooms 2 5 
to get houses from 2 to 5 rooms

http://redis.io/commands/zrange

key to redis is to check the commands and test them :)